# Modify conditional titles to include parent and page number

Tags: title, conditional-tags

Using conditional titles with title-tag rather than `wp_title()`, how do I add the immediate parent or ultimate grandparent to the title and,for multi-paged posts, the page number?

When using `wp_title()`, this added page numbers to multi-page posts:

```
if ($paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 ) echo ' ' . sprintf( __('(page %s)'), max($paged, $page) );
```

It doesn't work with title-tag.
And I've never known how to prepend with parent/grandparent

Comment: What is a "conditional title"?

Comment: Conditional titles are where the html title is changed according to various conditions. Typically it's done for SEO.

Comment: `wp_title()` does that too. Please show us your exact code.

Comment: @toscho... wp_title() is due to be deprecated, hence my switch. I've updated the original question to include existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to hook into the title by using wp_title filter

```
function se_custom_title( $title ) {
 if(x == y) {   
  $title = 'something'. $title;
 }
 return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'se_custom_titles' );
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that doesn't work with title-tag enabled themes. [link] (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218634/cant-get-wp-title-filter-working-in-twenty-sixteen-child-theme)